# How to run expo eas custom builds on ios device for development

Tags: react-native, expo, eas

I am using expo but with eas custom builds to support some native code integration and I would like to test and develop on my ios device but couldn't find a way to install development builds to my device.

I am creating a local build with

`eas build -p ios --profile development --local`

then it puts out a `tar.gz` file and then by exporting this file, I can drag and drop it on a simulator window to install.

However how could I use it to develop on my ios device?

I have tried building it through remote eas with

`eas build --profile development --platform ios`

but it does the same thing (as expected) without creating a QR code or link to be able to install on my device.

I have checked every documentation and now I honestly started to think that it may not be possible to test and develop eas custom builds on ios devices.

any help is much appreciated.

Comment: First you need to create provisioning profile certificate, create the ipa build then you can upload to website https://installonair.com/ get link to install on you IOS device